# Can i get the "Alias" of an application from an IIS Site with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-core

I am trying to grab the information shown in IIS when you run the UI, namely the list of "Applications" running under a site.
I'm aware that the UI refers to this as the "Alias".

[image: UI of IIS showing Alias property]

This value is not the same as "Name", nor is it the same as "host name".

I've tried the following:

```
$sites = Get-ChildItem "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site" | Where-Object { $_.NodeType -eq "Application" }
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    $alias = ($webSite.Name.Split("\"))[-1]
}
```

This returns the wrong values (for example, it may return api/mike rather than "Mike")
Since the Alias is not necessarily the hostname minus a slash, this standard and often referred to answer does not work.

I've also tried:

```
import-module webadministration

$apppools = (Get-IISAppPool).Name

foreach($appPool in $appPools) {

    $apps = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[`@applicationPool='$appPool']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).ItemXPath 

    foreach ($s in $apps) {
        $name = $s -replace "\/system.applicationHost\/sites\/site\[\@name='", ""
        $name = $name -replace "' and \@id='\d{1,10}'\]\/application\[\@path='", ""
        $name = $name -replace "'\]",""
        $name = $name -replace "Default Web Site/", ""
        $out += $name + "`n"
    }

    $out
}
```

This also provides the "api/Mike" value, rather than "Mike".

I've then tried, without any success:

```
$Binding = (Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site -Name Bindings).Collection.bindingInformation
$HostName = ($Binding -split ":")[-1]
```

and the often quoted answer of:

```
$app = get-webapplication
foreach($a in $app)
{
$a.Attributes[0].Value;
}
```

Again, these all produce the wrong value. (and "api/" is not the only prefix, sometimes you have "Default Web Site/api/..." among others)

Is there a way to get the list as shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `IIS:` PowerShell [drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) is provided by the obsolete [`WebAdministration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration) module.
- Its successor module, [`IISAdministration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration), doesn't provide such a *drive* anymore, but its cmdlets (`*-IIS*`, e.g. `Get-IISSite`) provide output objects that are easier to work with, as they are instances of the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration) .NET API namespace.

  - See [this announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets) and [this blog post](https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell#iis-powershell-modules-and-os-versions) for background information.

---

[`Get-IISSite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite) outputs [`Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.site) instances that have an `.Application` collection whose elements are [`Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.application) instances, whose [`.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.application.path#microsoft-web-administration-application-path) property seems to correspond what is shown as `Alias` in the IIS administration GUI, but *prefixed with `/`*, with the default application of a site always having path `/`; for *nested* applications, the alias is the *last `/`-separated token*.

Therefore, the following should list all aliases for the `Default Web Site` site's non-default *top-level* applications:

```bash
@((Get-IISSite 'Default Web Site').Applications.Path) -replace '.*/' -ne ''
```

- `-replace '.*/'` trims everything up to and including the last (or only) `/` character from the `.Path` property values.

  - Note that `.Path` is applied to the `.Applications` *collection*, yet it is the `.Path` property values of *its elements* that are returned, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature.
- `-ne ''` filters out the top-level default application (whose path is `/`)
- The [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) enclosure ensures that the returned paths are treated as an *array* even if only *one* path happens to be returned (`/`), which in turn ensures that `-replace` outputs an array so that the `-ne` operation acts as *filter* to weed out empty-string elements (in effect then returning an empty array); without it, `-ne` would return a *Boolean*, i.e. `$false`.

  - Note: This behavior - a Boolean result with a *scalar* LHS vs. a filtered sub-array with an *array* LHS - is [common to all of PowerShell's comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).